# How to accurately determine the remaining time of your laptop battery

Tags: laptop, battery, battery-life

I have a big issue with the estimated battery life of my laptop

[image]

Though it states that i have an estimated 2hrs 23min battery life before the battery runs out , it normally lasts me only 0.7 hrs to 1.2 hrs depending if I am using the internet , what programs are being run . The estimates are too off for my liking . I realised the estimates for most laptop are quite off also

I am wondering if there is any software or programs I can use use to accurately determine the remaining time of my battery life , It does not have to exact but can have around 5~10 % room for error .

Comment: On modern systems, due to pretty agressive power management, I find that remaining time is VERY variable on what you're doing. Things like what browser I use, or whether I've set the computer to speaker on silent can have up to a half hour difference on a 4 hour battery. It might help to say how old or new your system is to get a more accurate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check these two old posts (from 2009); one [from LifeHacker](http://lifehacker.com/5334722/batterycare-displays-detailed-battery-information) and one [from MakeUseOf](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/two-replacements-for-the-windows-laptop-battery-icon/).

For some slightly less dated software, try [BatteryBarPro](http://batterybarpro.com). It wants you to pay $8, but if you scroll down to the bottom there's a free version as well. I haven't actually used it, so I don't know how well either version  works.

Good Luck!